# What's the second name of the computer scientist Cliff B. Jones?

Tags: computer-scientists

The first name of the computer scientist [Cliff B. Jones](http://homepages.cs.ncl.ac.uk/cliff.jones) is, apparently, [Clifford](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cliff_Jones_(computer_scientist)). What is his second name?

Comment: If it happens that Cliff is mentioned in any book by D.E. Knuth, then look in the index of that book for the full name.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar Good hint! Unfortunately, I don't have any of Knuth's book at my disposal, and books.google.com doesn't provide me with a reliable answer.

Comment: Maybe [Jones, Professor Clifford Bryn](https://www.raeng.org.uk/about-us/the-fellowship/list-of-fellows?fa=j&p=2)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thx! What does “FREng” mean in the Web paged you linked? And the year after the colon?

Comment: It is from the site of Royal Academy of Engineering... thus, I suppose Fellow Royal Eng or something like that. Is it relevant for the History of Science?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA It is relevant to determining whether we are talking about the same guy. Cliff and Clifford are not unusual names, and Jones is a very widespread one. You understand. Anyhow, after checking, your suggestion for the second name sounds not unreasonable.

Comment: It is something more than a suggestion... :-) In the bio that you have linked I've found: "I am a Fellow of the Royal Academy of Engineering (FREng), ACM, BCS, and IET" and I've searched into the website of the Royal Academy of Engineering (linked above).

Comment: Riffing on Catch-22,  suggestions:  "B."  ,  "Be"  , "Before"   :-)